# Set field as string with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

Is there an alternative (better) way of doing this than using JSON.parse?

```
userSchema.methods.incrementPlaylist = function(playlist, value) {
  return this.update(JSON.parse("{\"$inc\": {\"playlists." + playlist + "\": " + value + "}}"));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, build up your update object like this instead:

```js
userSchema.methods.incrementPlaylist = function(playlist, value) {
  var update = { $inc: {} };
  update.$inc['playlists.' + playlist] = value;
  return this.update(update);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I was stuck with object literals, I knew I was missing something...